# Is it possible to send data directly to a constructor?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

First time using Node.js, Mongodb, Express for web-development.

Say you have a constructor `'CreateObject'` in a file separate from your routing or driver file.

Can I use `module.exports.CreateObject`, and then simply require and create the object from within the driver, so that I can call a single function and have the database insert data directly into the object for me when I call it in my routing file?

(i.e. 'When user visits page, import the CreateObject constructor, `db.insert(CreateObject object, data)`, now export that information to our display functions)

Does export work like that?

I'm trying to avoid routing every file to my display functions by adding each entry to an array with `'./:collection/:item'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express doesn't really care about constructors or objects. You can certainly use them, but then you need to do some plumbing to use them within a middleware function. Instead, you might want to think in terms of middleware functions.

A common pattern in node development is to define one (or more) middleware functions in other files and then require those into your app. You can chain an arbitrary number of middleware functions together and attach them to a route. Like this:

```
// app.js
var dbInserter = require('./myDbInserter.js');
app.use('/:collection/:item', dbInserter, otherMiddleware ... );

// myDbInserter.js
module.exports = function(req,res,next) {
  var collectionName = req.params.collection;
  var itemId = req.params.item;
  // create object, insert into db, etc.
  next();
}
```